# Jquery Mobile Table in PHP code

Tags: php

I am implementing [this](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/tables/table-column-toggle.html) Jquery Mobile Table in my PHP web page.

I am running into a problem however. Because I am working in PHP, I am unable to use tags such as `<table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" id="my-table">` inside my code.

For example:

```
echo "<table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" id="my-table">
  <tr><th data-priority="1">Mare</th><th data-priority="2">Stallion</th><th data-priority="3">Covering Date</th><th data-priority="5">Ovulation Scan</th><th data-priority="6">Pregnancy Scan</th></tr>";
```

...does not work. Is there anyway of working around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not alternating between single- and double-quotes, you're essentially closing and re-opening your strings, which will cause issues. Try this:

```
echo '<table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" id="my-table">'
  . '<thead><tr>'
  . '<th data-priority="1">Mare</th>'
  . '<th data-priority="2">Stallion</th>'
  . '<th data-priority="3">Covering Date</th>'
  . '<th data-priority="5">Ovulation Scan</th>'
  . '<th data-priority="6">Pregnancy Scan</th></tr></thead>';
```

Also note the period (`.`). This is a concatenation operator that lets you join strings together to make them more readable. They're handy when coding, since it allows you to display code in a nicer format.

Comment: Thanks very much Chris, that seems to have worked, however I still have one more problem. When I deselect a column from the columns tab, only the column name disappears, that columns rows still appear! any idea where i might be going wrong?

Comment: It looks like you need to wrap the `<tr>` element in a `<thead>` (which is the 'table head'). I did update my answer to include the `<thead>` opening and closing tags.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much Chris, great help! :)