# How can I get a Jquery Mobile table to echo out in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, html-table, echo

I am attempting to echo out a JQM table in `viewsessions.php` file. I have researched the topic and tried this [Jquery Mobile Table in PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639986/jquery-mobile-table-in-php-code) solution, but the page does not load with my code, so I have stripped it back to where the table works.

Any ideas how to do this?

**viewsessions.php**

```
<?php

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";

// This code creates a connection to the MySQL database in PHPMyAdmin named 'ibill'
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','cornwall','ibill');

// The connection is then checked, if it fails, an echo is sent back to the page stating a connection error.
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// This is the query that is sent to the ibill database.
$viewsessions = "SELECT typeofactivity, employer, date, time, amount FROM session_details";
$result = $con->query($viewsessions);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr>
                    <th>Type of Activity</th>
                    <th>Employer</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Amount (GBP)</th>
                </tr>";
// output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row["typeofactivity"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["employer"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["date"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["time"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["amount"]."</td>
            </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$con->close();
?>
```

I am using multiple pages inside one html file so have just posted the page with the relevant code below..

**main.php#viewsessions**

```
  <!--**********************************************VIEW SESSIONS PAGE*******************************************************************************-->
  <!--***********************************************************************************************************************************************-->

  <!--********************************HEADER**************************************************************************************-->
  <div data-role="page" id="viewsessions">
      <div data-role="header" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
      <div class='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
           <li class='active'><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
           <li><a href='#sessionrecord'>Record a Session</a></li>
           <li><a href='#viewsessions'>View Sessions</a></li>
           <li><a href='#invoice'>Create an Invoice</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /header -->
  <!--********************************HEADER***************************************************************************************-->

  <!--********************************MAIN*****************************************************************************************-->
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <p><span class="logout"><a href="logout.php" data-role="button">Sign Out</a></span></p>
      <div class="loginphp">
        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_session']) and $_SESSION['user_session']!=""){
        echo '<p>Signed in as:&nbsp;<span class="uname">' . $_SESSION['user_session'] . '</span></p>';      }
        else {
        echo 'not working';
        }
        ?>
      </div>



      <img class="mainlogo" src="/projects/ibill_v3/img/ibill logo.png" alt="iBill Logo" width="200" height="152">
          <h1>Recorded Sessions</h1>  
          <section class="maincontent">
             <?php
              include "viewsessions.php";
             ?>
          </section>
    </div>
  <!--********************************MAIN******************************************************************************************-->

  <!--********************************FOOTER****************************************************************************************-->
    <div data-role="footer">
      <footer class="footer">
        <p>awilliams&copy;</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--********************************FOOTER*****************************************************************************************-->

  <!--**********************************************************END OF VIEW SESSIONS PAGE***************************************************************-->
  <!--**************************************************************************************************************************************************-->
```

Comment: Your server code looks good. Could you post the relevant html code as well?

Comment: I have updated my question to include the relevant html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are updating table from server you need to rebuild it using `( ".selector" ).table( "rebuild" );`
otherwise you might just need to reinitialize the table

```
$( ".selector" ).table({
  defaults: true
});
```

moreover you need to include `data-role="table"` attribute in your table tag 
and i think that might be your problem cause you did not insert it
try to include that tag , and if it didn't work use the below code

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo '<table data-role="table" class="selector" data-mode="reflow"> <tr>
                    <th>Type of Activity</th>
                    <th>Employer</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Amount (GBP)</th>
                </tr>';
// output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row["typeofactivity"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["employer"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["date"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["time"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["amount"]."</td>
            </tr>";
    }
    echo '</table><script> $( ".selector" ).table({
      defaults: true
    });</script>';
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Hi Hatem Ahmed, I just tried this code and it didn't work. I also replaced " for ' on the table attributes just in case, but it still didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Send the buffered HTML and I will give it a try

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" ).table({ ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\ibill_v3\html\viewsessions.php on line 39

Comment: Updated typo try it again

Comment: " instead of ' on the jquery rebuild part sorry for typi

Answer (score 1):

You PHP code looks OK, and so do your HTML. Note that if your PHP code works correct, the table will be generated as a part of the HTML document *before* the jQuery Mobile styling and enhancment. Please check that your PHP code actually returns the desired HTML code. This can be done by copy/paste the code to a separate script and run it directly.

Also consider to add the following check for good practice. The reason is that `$con->query()` might return FALSE, while `$result->num_rows` expects a `mysqli_result` object.

```
// This is the query that is sent to the ibill database.
$viewsessions = "SELECT typeofactivity, employer, date, time, amount FROM session_details";
$result = $con->query($viewsessions);

//Check if a result was returned
if($result === FALSE){
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}
```